# Wrong picture on FB Wall, feed post from android app (android FB sdk)

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have a problem with Feed post Picture, we decided to change our (android native) FB App icon, so we changed this icon at all occurrences in FB app settings, and we changed the picture on ftp server(on which we refferenced when posting feed from app).

But when I post feed from app (in the feed dialog there is a correct picture), on wall in browser there is wrong(old) picture, weird is when I check my wall from katana(facebook android app), there is a correct picture. Size of picture is 512x512 and it's png format.
I'm talking about picture besides the feed (not small icon under feed)

Sample of feed post:

```
...
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("picture", path_tou_our_icon_on_ftp_server_in_png_fromat);
parameters.putString("name", facebookMsgName);
parameters.putString("caption", facebookMsgCaption);
parameters.putString("description", facebook_message);
parameters.putString("link", "http://bit.ly/....");
facebook.dialog(mInstance, "feed", parameters,....
```

Comment: If you [debug](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) the `link` url does it show the old image that is being displayed?

Comment: if I past link into browser it shows correct(new) image

Comment: Paste it into the browser? That's not what I asked, in the facebook debug tool, what's the result?

Answer (score 1):

Add `"?cache=" + System.currentTimeMillis();`   to your image URL posted to FB.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because facebook are probably caching your image. There are two solutions:

- Give the new image a different name and update your code to use it. This will force facebook to use the new image, but it means you have to get a update for you app through the App Store, or
- Wait for Facebook to update it's cache and start using the correct new image.

Comment: Thnx, make sense for me, and have you idea how long it takes (roughly) until FB updates its cache?(days/weeks/months) I put new icon +- 2 weeks ago, and still wrong icon is displayed.

Comment: No idea mate. It's not documented anywhere.